# select similar values from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I have several data s in `MySQL` database. In my table there is a column called rank. what I want is when some one enter a rank say `25` then the result should display names on similar(+ or -) ranks `LIMIT` to `10` from table.

example

```
mathew - 25
john - 26
joe - 25
stewart - 27
kelly - 24
brandon -23
magy - 22 .......etc.
```

Thanks
Mathew

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make use of the MySQL's `between` and `limit` clause for this:

```
$range = 5;  // you'll be selecting around this range. 
$min = $rank - $range;
$max = $rank + $range;
$limit = 10; // max number of results you want. 

$query = "select * from table where rank between $min and $max limit $limit";
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT data FROM table WHERE rank>=25 LIMIT 0,10

Answer (score 0):

you can use `BETWEEN`:

```
SELECT *
  FROM `table`
 WHERE `rank` BETWEEN $input-5 AND $input+5
 LIMIT 10
```

of course make sure you're input is validated/sanitized or use prepared statements. the code above is pseudocode to explain how you'd do it language agnostic (apart from the sql part ;))